# Exclude members in a dimension attribute

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

Is there a way in a SSAS cube to exclude members in a dimension attribute by changing the dimension structure? I am wanting a solution that doesn't use perspectives.

Example:

```
California
    - Los Angeles
    - Sacremento
    - San Francisco
```

Let's say in the above hierarchy I wanted to exclude Sacremento. Is there a way to exclude this members and others by changing the dimension structure, or is the only possibiltiy to use a perspective?

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 possibilities:

1. Place a filter on the queries of the data source view of the UDM and remove any data you do not want to see in the cube.
2. Set security on your cube and deny access to the sacremento member of that dimension for a certain role.
3. Write specific MDX queries that exclude dimension members, e.g.

   Except(
       [States].Members,
       [States].[Sacremento]
   )